# Add a path if the url has error param in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, url, react-router-dom

```
import { Provider } from 'jotai'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App.tsx'
import Auth from './Auth.tsx'
import NewPass from './NewPass.tsx'
import ResetPassword from './ResetPassEmail.tsx'
import './index.css'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Auth />,
  },
  {
    path: "/chatroom",
    element: <App />,
  },
  {
    path: "/psdResetEmail",
    element: <ResetPassword />,
  },
  {
    path: "/psdReset/:access_token=:access_token&token_type=:token_type&type=:type",
    element: <NewPass />,
  },
  {
    path: "/psdReset/:error=:error&error_code=:error_code&error_description=:error_description",
    element: <Auth />,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I am currently using this method to create routers, but I am getting errors when I am trying to create new paths for `access_token` and `error` but getting back 404 error.

The error URL looks like this: `"http://localhost:5173/psdReset#error=unauthorized_client&error_code=401&error_description=Email+link+is+invalid+or+has+expired"`

The `access_token` URL looks the same but with `access_token` params.

I am trying to use the URL hash.

Comment: Are you trying to read the URL hash, or queryString, in the routes?

Comment: I am trying to read URL hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route` component's `path` prop only uses the URL path part for route matching, adding the hash/queryString won't work and actually breaks route matching.

I suggest creating a single component that can read the hash/queryString and conditionally render the routed component or issue a back navigation if there isn't a "match".

Example:

```
const PasswordReset = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { hash } = useLocation();
  
  // Create a URLSearchParams object from the hash value
  const searchParams = React.useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(hash), [hash]);

  // Unpack any token values
  const accessToken = searchParams.get("access_token");
  const tokenType = searchParams.get("token_type");

  // Unpack any error values
  const error = searchParams.get("error");
  const errorCode = searchParams.get("error_code");
  const errorDescription = searchParams.get("error_description");

  // Compute which component type you want to render
  const isNewPass = accessToken && tokenType;
  const isAuth = error && errorCode && errorDescription;

  useEffect(() => {
    // If no "match" then navigate back
    if (!(isNewPass || isAuth)) {
      navigate(-1);
    }
  }, [isNewPass, isAuth, navigate]);

  // Render appropriate "match"
  if (isNewPass) {
    return <NewPass />;
  } else if (isAuth) {
    return <Auth />;
  }

  // No "match" render null
  return null;
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Auth />,
  },
  {
    path: "/chatroom",
    element: <App />,
  },
  {
    path: "/psdResetEmail",
    element: <ResetPassword />,
  },
  {
    path: "/psdReset",
    element: <PasswordReset />,
  },
]);
```